# How to combine two image masks got through np.zeros(src_img.shape[:2], np.uint8) and np.zeros(differentimage.shape[:2], np.uint8)?

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

Actually guys, I have obtained one mask from 
cv2.grabCut(src_img,mask1,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,3,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
and the other one is i have obtained by drawing scribbles on the image 
i.e 
cv2.circle(self.mask2,(x,y),self.thickness,self.value['val'],-1)
both masks are initialized as 
np.zeros(src_img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
, 
I want to combine these two masks like
mask3=mask1 & mask2

and give this new mask to Grabcat,
i don;t want to concatenate them, i want to select the common zeros,1;s and 2's values in these two numpy arrays. 
Your guidance in solving this problem will be highly appreciated?
Best regards

Comment: Do this masks have different shapes?

Comment: No they have the same shape

Comment: Then `mask3 = mask1 & mask2` should be valid. Does it give you wrong result? If it's wrong can you add the example of what result you got and what you are expecting?